# How to copy region of text in some app (like using Alt key in some Win apps)?

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, 10.10, 10.04

In Windows, when I want to copy some region of text I press `Alt` key and then mark the region with mouse.

If I try to do this in Ubuntu, then I activate the `move screen` command.

How can I achieve the same effect in Ubuntu? It's funny, but I can to find this on Google, thou is seems to be very useful feature.

Comment: With region, you mean a block of columns, not just rows? In xpdf, a pdf-viewer, you can do it - it is the normal way to mark text there (left button, afair).

Comment: @userunknown I meant, that I am not bound to full row or full column. For example I have 2 lines of text, and I want to select only first 3 letter of each word. I Windows I can use alt+mouse on any text to achieve such selection.

Comment: @userunknown To add: I know I can do it in PDF, but I need it in normal text editor.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with `columns`. A rectangular region, not bound to whole lines.

Comment: @userunknown Any ideas?

Comment: If anyone knows of any other text editor that supports this feature, please right it here.

Comment: which Windows editor are you using this feature in? surely not notepad?

Comment: @prusswan Hm I do not use notepad but MS Word.

Comment: It would be better to rephrase your question, since it is perplexing to Windows users even. The feature you described is not native to Windows OS

Comment: @prusswan I think it's better title now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is dependent on the text editor you're using. In `kate`, for example, Block Selection Mode is toggled by Shift-Ctrl-B.

As far as I'm aware, on Windows this also is a feature which is implemented (or not implemented) by each individual editor.

If your editor does not support the feature you can install kate, copy-paste text there and then use the Block Selection Mode.

Comment: cool suggestion. Do you know any text editor in GNOME that supports this. I wouldn't like to install all KDE libs just because of the Kate.

Comment: actually it's only 4MB of space so that's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Where in Windows? You can't possibly do that in Notapad.
I imagine you use Notepad++ or similar Scintilla based editor.

Same can be done in Ubuntu, only that you can't use Alt key because it's reserved, but Ctrl. Try it with Geany, SciTE or maybe other Scinilla based editors

Comment: Thanks! And not, its not Notepad. It's MS Word. In this post I realized that this feature is in the domain of the app, not operating system. I will upvote your reply.